# Too many drivers in 'Additional Drivers'

Tags: drivers, nvidia, additional-drivers

I was trying to install CUDA and because of some misunderstanding I installed many NVIDIA drivers. Now I have purged all NVIDIA drivers. But when I open 'Additional Drivers', it is showing too many options.

[image: Here is Screenshot]

How should I remove unnecessary drivers ?

Comment: Why remove options? Options are good. If one driver doesn't work, you get to try the others.

Answer (score 2):

This screen shows available drivers, that you can install from repositories.

According to your screen neither of the drivers are installed, so there is nothing to remove.

The Nouveau driver is the default open source drivers that is always installed. Others are proprietary Nvidia drivers.

The ones you see as open source are proprietary drivers from a PPA. The system can't detect that they are proprietary because they come from an unofficial repository

Comment: Thanks. Just a question out of curiosity ! How can I know that which are `available drivers` and which are `installed drivers` ?

Comment: The one that is selected is the installed one. When Nouveau is selected, nothing is installed.